# не пойму почему werkzeug.routing.BuildError

Tags: flask, slug

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Blueprint index page
{% endblock %}

{% block content_title %}
    Posts
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% for post in posts %} 
    <h5>
        <a href="{{ url_for('posts.post_detail', slug=post.slug) }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h5>
    {% endfor %}


<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


{% endblock %}
```

**blueprint.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template

from models import Post, Tag
from .forms import PostForm

from flask import request
from app import db

from flask import redirect
from flask import url_for


posts = Blueprint('posts', __name__, template_folder='templates')


@posts.route('/create', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def create_post():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        body = request.form['body']

        try:
            post = Post(title=title, body=body)
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            print('Something wrong')

        return redirect( url_for('posts.index') )

    form = PostForm()
    return render_template('posts/create_post.html', form=form)

@posts.route('/')
def index():

    q = request.args.get('q')

    if q:
        posts = Post.query.filter(Post.title.contains(q) | Post.body.contains(q)).all()
    else:
        posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.created.desc()) #all()
    return render_template('posts/index.html', posts=posts)


@posts.route('/<slug>')
def post_detail(slug):
    post = Post.query.filter(Post.slug==slug).first()
    tags = post.tags
    return render_template('posts/post_detail.html', post=post, tags=tags)



@posts.route('/tag/<slug>')
def tag_detail(slug):
    tag = Tag.query.filter(Tag.slug==slug).first()
    posts = tag.posts.all()
    return render_template('posts/tag_detail.html', tag=tag, posts=posts)
```

ну и сам веркцойг

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'posts.post_detail'. Did you forget to specify values ['slug']?

Traceback (most recent call last)
This is the Copy/Paste friendly version of the traceback. You can also paste this traceback into a gist:  create paste
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/kiril/desktop/flask/app/posts/blueprint.py", line 45, in index
    return render_template('posts/index.html', posts=posts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 116, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 989, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 754, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/kiril/desktop/flask/app/posts/templates/posts/index.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
  File "/home/kiril/desktop/flask/app/templates/base.html", line 54, in top-level template code
    {% block content %}
  File "/home/kiril/desktop/flask/app/posts/templates/posts/index.html", line 15, in block "content"
    <a href="{{ url_for('posts.post_detail', slug=post.slug) }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 333, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1805, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 323, in url_for
    force_external=external)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1768, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'posts.post_detail'. Did you forget to specify values ['slug']?
```

Comment: Попробуйте в отладочных целях вывести `<a href="#">{{ post.slug }}</a>`

Comment: вывел список статей(название)

Comment: решенно!!
оказывается когда пилил тестовые записи в таблицу
не написал обработку на пустой запрос записи в таблицу
ну и естественно когда нажимаешь сохранить пустой пост он его смело пишет с пустыми полями, от сюда и вылазиет беда при генерации слага)) крч пахать и пахать еще)